# Java format array (using the Formatter class)

Tags: java, string, format

We have method that looks like this :

```
public String getCommandString(Object...args) {
    return this.code + " " + String.format(this.pattern, args);
}
```

Where `this.code:int`  and `this.pattern:String`.

This method is usually called like this :

```
// cmd.code = 20
// cmd.pattern = "%1$s = %2$d"
String str = cmd.getCommandString("foo", 3);   // -> "20 foo = 3"
```

and other string patterns (this is for a very simple text-based server-client program)

Now, is it possible for pattern to take into account a variable number of arguments, such as

```
// cmd.code = 20
// cmd.pattern = ???
String s1 = cmd.getCommandString("a", "b", "c");               // -> 20 a b c
String s2 = cmd.getCommandString("Hello", "world");            // -> 20 Hello world
String s3 = cmd.getCommandString("1", "2, "3", "4", "5", "6"); // -> 20 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Assuming perhaps that each argument is of the same type (strings)? Or do I have to override the method and format the string manually? More specifically, I'm looking for a generic string pattern to format a variable number of arguments (of the same type). I remember making such a thing in C, but is this possible in Java?

Comment: I don't get it. Can't you just concatenate everything? (and if you have a pattern, just run each string through the pattern and concatenate the results)

Comment: Yes for the specific example cited, calling `StringUtils.join(args, ' ')` is the way to go, but the I think the OP was just using that as an example. :)

Comment: I am aware of third party classes to manipulate objects (such as `StringUtils`) but usually turn to the `java.*` packages first, if I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality you are asking for, if I understand it correctly, does not exist.  Here is the javadoc section from the `Formatter` class:

> Format specifiers can reference arguments in three ways:
>
> Explicit indexing is used when the format specifier contains an argument index. The argument index is a decimal integer indicating the position of the argument in the argument list. The first argument is referenced by "1$", the second by "2$", etc. An argument may be referenced more than once. For example:
>
> formatter.format("%4$s %3$s %2$s %1$s %4$s %3$s %2$s %1$s",
>                       "a", "b", "c", "d")
>      // -> "d c b a d c b a"
>
> Relative indexing is used when the format specifier contains a '<' ('\u003c') flag which causes the argument for the previous format specifier to be re-used. If there is no previous argument, then a MissingFormatArgumentException is thrown.
>
> formatter.format("%s %s % "a b b b"
>       // "c" and "d" are ignored because they are not referenced
>
> Ordinary indexing is used when the format specifier contains neither an argument index nor a '<' flag. Each format specifier which uses ordinary indexing is assigned a sequential implicit index into argument list which is independent of the indices used by explicit or relative indexing.
>
> formatter.format("%s %s %s %s", "a", "b", "c", "d")
>      // -> "a b c d"
>
> It is possible to have a format string which uses all forms of indexing, for example:
>
> formatter.format("%2$s %s % "b a a b"
>      // "c" and "d" are ignored because they are not referenced
>
> The maximum number of arguments is limited by the maximum dimension of a Java array as defined by the Java Virtual Machine Specification. If the argument index is does not correspond to an available argument, then a MissingFormatArgumentException is thrown.
>
> If there are more arguments than format specifiers, the extra arguments are ignored.

What you are asking for is a way to construct a pattern that will accept an arbitrary number of arguments and use tham all.  The problem is that the `Formatter` class can only associate format specifiers with arguments either explicitly, relatively, or ordinarily.  In each of these cases, **the number of forma specifiers is fixed**. There is no construct in which you can repeat or loop a format specifier.  The relative technique looks promising, but there is no way to nest, or loop, it.

Comment: I was hoping for some nifty undocumented tricks, but looks like this will not work. I'll make due using other methods then.

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
public String getCommandString(Object...args) {
    // Want to have a "-" if args are not given
    return this.code + " " + args != null && args.length > 0
            ? Arrays.stream(args).map(o -> o.toString()).collect(Collectors.joining(" + ")) : "-";
}
```